# Parametrized forms in Yesod

Tags: forms, haskell, yesod

I'm trying to create a pair of forms in a (scaffolded) Yesod setup where:
 form 1 allows a user to choose a file.  That file is parsed into a set of records and then the user is given
  form 2 which has a selectFieldList for choosing a record.

So I have

```
form2::[(Text,Record)]->Form Record
form2 recordInfo = ...
```

which is fine for when I generate it (`generateFormPost $ form2 recordInfo`) .  But to process the result, I will be in a different handler and I no longer have the list of `(Text,Record)` pairs to give to the `form2` function in order to execute `runFormPost` (`runFormPost $ form2 ??`).  So I can't get the data from the form.

I realize this is a consequence of the statelessness of the RESTful web.  And I realize there are some ways out of this.  I could use persistent and hand some sort of key to the handler so it knows where to get the `(Text,Record)` data.  Or I could use session somehow?  Or cookies?

This web stuff is new to me so before I launch in a silly direction, I was wondering if there is a simple answer I am missing and, if not, what is the "right" way to handle forms that depend on dynamic data in this way?

Comment: As far as general web solutions go, I would either store the data from form 1 in a hidden field of form 2 (that way when form 2 is submitted, you have the data from both forms) or I would combine both parts into one form and use Javascript show part 2 of the form after they do part 1.

Comment: Thanks! I think my data structures are too complicated for hidden fields to work easily but even if they weren't, how would that work?  I need to give the data (the recordInfo) as an argument to runFormPost before I can get the data so having the data in the form isn't much help.  I think the javascript idea could work though it would also need ajax since the later fields depend on (the server) parsing the chosen files.  But I think I'd rather learn how to use a DB rather than all the javascript and ajax.  At least for now...